# Updating whether data mapping successful in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two table `abc` and `xyz`. I am inserting `consolidated_table`  data into these table like.

```
create or replace
PACKAGE body       XX_package_name
AS

procedure move_data
is 

begin

insert into tabe abc
(colum1 ,
column2,
column3)

select column1,column3,column4 from consolidated_table;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  dbms_output.put_line ('ERROR: print_out :: ' || SUBSTR (sqlerrm, 1, 230));

end;

begin

insert into tabe xyz
(colum1 ,
column2,
column3)

select column1,column3,column4 from consolidated_table;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  dbms_output.put_line ('ERROR: print_out :: ' || SUBSTR (sqlerrm, 1, 230));

end;


end;
```

Now i have 2 columns in `consolidated_table` as `error_messgae` and `processed`.

I have to update these column values such as if the data is succesfully inserted into `abc/xyz`  then `processed` column should be populated and if unsucessfult `error_message` column should be populated.
Any idea how should i go about it..I have to insert this logic within my begin block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use a cursor and loop through each item, if it inserts into both tables without an error and updates the consolidated table everything is good, if there is an error it will rollback and update the consolidated table with the error message you specify.

```
create procedure move_data
is
    temp_cur sys_refcursor;
    tmpCol1 consolidated_tbl.col1%Type;
    tmpCol2 consolidated_tbl.col2%Type;
    tmpCol3 consolidated_tbl.col3%Type;
begin
    begin
        open temp_cur for
        select  col1, col2, col3
        from consolidated_tbl
        where processed = 'N';

        loop
        fetch temp_cur into tmpCol1, tmpCol2, tmpCol3;
        exit when temp_cur%notfound;
            begin
                insert into abc (col1, col2, col3)
                values (tmpCol1, tmpCol2, tmpCol3);

                insert into xyz (col1, col2, col3)
                values (tmpCol1, tmpCol2, tmpCol3);

                update consolidated_tbl
                set processed = 'Y', err_msg = null
                where col1 = tmpCol1;

                exception
                when others then
                begin
                    rollback;
                    dbms_output.put_line('Failure: Rollback.');
                    update consolidated_tbl
                    set processed = 'N', err_msg = 'Could not insert into tables.'
                    where col1 = tmpCol1;
                end;
            end;    
            commit;
        end loop;
    end;
end;
```

If you wanted to get more granular with your error messages to specify which table it errored on, you could add the exception block to each statement, and update a message with the proper one by concatenating messages together. Then at the end check for the message being null or not, if it isn't do your rollback and update the message in the table for that record.

Also as a note on the use of exceptions, this is just an example, in a real-world use, you should capture specific exceptions instead of just `others`. For example, say you tried to insert into a table and the record already existed causing a PK violation. You may not want to mark that as a failure in the consolidated table, but you could still add the error message to it as a warning or note.

Comment: I have to do this for 26 tables with consolidated tables having more than 10 columns... this approach will become lengthy

Comment: @divya.trehan573 - I have been on vacation, did this answer help at all?